# Real-time watching of a CSV being written to in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

We have a piece of lab equipment that consistently writes tab-delimited records to a CSV file and I am tasked with writing an app to consume that data. That part is easy. However, on top of this I am also tasked with finding a way to "watch" this file in "real-time" through a WPF app using data-binding. There are two advantages I have to help make this an easier task.

1. Records written to the CSV happen at an interval of 8 seconds.
2. For the total period of time that I need to watch the CSV, the file itself will almost never grow to be larger than 100mb - if that. Most of the files I have seen are 20-30mb.

**My Question**

Is there a way to open a file and maintain a "constant" read or watch of its contents or do I have to do this using classic file IO polling?

**My thought process in attempting to solve this problem**

Rhetorically, I thought, "How is this CSV any different than a database?" but further [research](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a0e9e20f-66d2-447c-8b7e-75de18535e63) revealed that EF can't work with CSVs directly. If a DbContext in Entity Framework can be used with data-binding to report changes in a property, could I also set something up similar to watch the CSV change? But no matter what road I take metnally, any solution keeps coming back to "polling". For example, I could use Linq to hit the CSV periodically and return the result to a property and when the property's value changes (something has been added to the CSV) then the databinding would know of it and the app could act accordingly. Yeah that sounds like polling.

**In conclusion**

If there is an easier solution that leverages WPF/databinding or EF (if possible) or some .NET class I am not thinking of or have mentioned here to answer my question or solve my problem, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Why don't you just create a regular class? entity framework will not help here. You need to `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FileSystemWatcher to detect when the file length or last modify time has changed, as long as you're aware of the fact that a FSW doesn't behave well if it is ever unable to read the directory it's pointed at (e.g. because your connection to a share is interrupted; there are workarounds out there).

You're probably better off not keeping the file open, or you might interfere with the writer. Open-read-close when a change is detected, would be my advice.

EF isn't designed to work directly with files; it's designed to work with a database engine that is probably file-backed, which is a totally different thing. Fortunately, reading a CSV line isn't that difficult, and assuming it's append-only, keeping track of how far you've read so far and starting your next read at that point is also not a hard problem.

Comment: I had considered FSW but it is still based on polling, and that may be what I have to go for. I guess since I know it will be written to every 8 seconds, that would also kind of render FSW redundant as well.

Comment: FSW is _not_ based on polling. It hooks into the filesystem driver. It is however a bit difficult to use properly.

Comment: @CoryNelson Ill retract that short sighted comment. You are right. I intended to say that I could simply forgo the difficulty associated with FSW and poll since I know the file will be written to at a regular interval. FSW would reveal to me when it was being written to and I already know that. A thousand apologies! :)